# how can I spider my own website

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have installed a php script to ban bots that ignore my robots.txt file.  I'd like to test if its working properly.  is there a few lines of PHP code that I could use to simulate a bot spidering my site.  Perhaps crawl 'n' layers deep, create a simple text file of the results, and ignore my robots.txt file and ignore rel="nofollow".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget -r -l4 –spider -D thesite.com http://www.thesite.com
```

from http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/spider-a-website-with-wget/

Comment: wget is the easiest and the most economical solution to the question asked. For periodic crawling etc, or you'd like to use a sledge hammer to crack a nut then take a look at Apache Nutch - http://nutch.apache.org/

Comment: I have not heard of this before (im a newbiew im afraid).  How to I run the wget command and where from?

Comment: Run from the shell or use php exec

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

See also: http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications

Comment: Thank you.  I ran this as a php page and got the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_html() in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/bottest.php on line 6

Comment: ah.  Thank you.  dint see that.